# PySpark - Connection Refused to master

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, master-slave

Hi  I've just configured a Spark Cluster Mode and I'm trying to start pyspark shell but I'm getting an error. 
I have 2 slaves and 1 master in my cluster. My configuration worked fine and my master and workers are showing up in command line `jps` and also on my browser  with http://localhost:8080. 
But my problem is when I'm trying to enter to pyspark shell i'm getting this log :

```
**18/07/05 10:30:53 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to 
connect to master XXX.XX.XX.80:7077**
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
atorg.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$ano nfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /XXX.XX.XX.80:7077**
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: 
**Connexion refusée: /XXX.XX.XX.XX:7077**
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
... 1 more
```

PS: Connexion refusée means connection refused.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Lol, i'm a little ashamed of the solution, after configuring my cluster i didn't reboot so my machines didn't update the new host name that i give to them while the configuration. After rebooting the 3 machines, I managed to enter to PySpark shell.